# On changing rownum from dropdown in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, pager, rownum

When I make an entry to jqGrid, it is being added successfully. But immediately after that when I change the rowNum from the dropdownlist of the pager, the grid shows duplicate records.

When the page is reloaded, then the grid will have the correct entries and not the duplicate entries.

Can someone please help me with resolving this issue?

Comment: It is a good idea to post your code. Where is the data - at server or locally?  Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid , free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= 4.7

Comment: version of jqGrid is Guriddo jqGrid JS 4.7.1 and data comes from the server

Comment: Please, post your code in order to get help any other explanation will not help. Maybe you will need to check your server side code what is returned after this operation

Comment: $("#tblLocation").jqGrid({
                    datatype: 'local',
                    data : data})
This data is being returned from the server.Despite of that no code for this operation is written.